# Ground layout between two data acquisition boards

Tags: analog, adc, connector, ground

I'm designing a two-board data acquisition system for resistive and capacitive environmental sensors.

Board 1 hosts the sensors on a mezzanine daughter board (dashed lines) and contains the ADC for the resistive sensors. The sensors must be physically as close together as possible so their traces run very close to each other for about 3 cm and go through the same connector.

Board 2 is optional and contains the ADC ([AD7745](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7745.html)) for the capacitive sensor (P14, [pdf](https://www.ist-ag.com/sites/default/files/DHP14-FemtoCap_E.pdf)), which is floating (not grounded) and connected as per [AN-1585](http://www.analog.com/AD8515?doc=AN-1585.pdf).

For various reasons it's desirable to keep boards 1 and 2 separate for the first prototype, although they may be merged later.

[image]

How should I connect (if at all) the ground planes of board 1 and board 2 to minimise ground loops and coupling of the AC signal into the DC paths?

- not at all?
- directly at the connector ?
- with a capacitor, at the connector?
- extend the ground plane of board 2 as a guard around the blue traces up to the sensors' mezzanine connector?

Comment: It depends on what specifically the capacitive sensor is.

Comment: It's an SMD capacitive moisture sensor (IST P14).

Comment: data sheet please

Comment: added in original post

Comment: Extend the ground plane is my best guess.

Comment: thanks for the insight!